# How to make the focus/scroll move to an element on click and then back when clicked again?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a glyphicon that when clicked toggles an element so that it is now displayed, however I also need the page to give that element focus or scroll to that element.

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
  $('.glyphicon.glyphicon-comment').on('click', function() {
    $('.comments').slideToggle({
      duration: 500,
    });
    <% unless @photo.comments.count == 0 %> 
    $('body').animate( { scrollTop: $('.comments').offset().top
    }, 500);
    <% end %>
  }); 
});
```

This works when `$('.glyphicon')` is first clicked and the element comes into view, the problem is that when `$('.glyphicon')`, the `css` of `$('.comments')` is changed to `display: none`, but the second part of the code still scrolls down the page to where `$('.comments')` was located. I don't want that to happen, instead I want the page to scroll all the way up to the top (as if it had been reloaded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
    $('.glyphicon.glyphicon-comment').on('click', function() {
        if( $('.comments').css('display') != 'none') ) {  //if($('.comments').is(':visible')) - work too

            $('.comments').slideToggle({
              duration: 500,
            });

            <% unless @photo.comments.count == 0 %> 
              $('body').animate( { scrollTop: $('.comments').offset().top}, 500);
            <% end %>
        }else{
            $("body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
        }
    }); 
});
```

PS: For a better compatibility, you might want to use `$("html,body")` instead of `$("body")` when using scroll events